# check strlen and only send datas if fulfilled

Tags: php

I'm using inputs to send data to my database. I'm checking the input's length with strlen. I want to forbid users to send their data if any of the inputs are too long. This is how I check it:

**My Code is below:**

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('UPDATE cards SET name=?, phone=?, phone2=?, email=?, zipcode=?, address=?, job=?, description=?, visibility=?, confirmed=?  WHERE id = ?');

    if (
      strlen($name) < 30 &&
      strlen($job) < 50 &&
      strlen($zipcode) < 4 &&
      strlen($email) < 50 &&
      strlen($phone) < 20 &&
      strlen($phone2) < 20 &&
      strlen($address) < 50 &&
      strlen($description) < 500 &&
        $stmt &&
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssisssiii', $name, $phone, $phone2, $email, $zipcode, $address, $job, $description, $visibility, $confirmed, $id) &&
        $stmt -> execute()
        ) {
          echo "Succes";
    } else {
        echo $mysqli -> error;
    }
```

my database doesn't get the data this way. It only gets them if I remove the strlen parts, but then they can send as long inputs as they want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling `bind_param` and `execute` in the `if` statement?
It would make much more sense to run these commands **after** the input validation:

```
if (strlen($name) < 30 &&
    strlen($job) < 50 &&
    strlen($zipcode) < 4 &&
    strlen($email) < 50 &&
    strlen($phone) < 20 &&
    strlen($phone2) < 20 &&
    strlen($address) < 50 &&
    strlen($description) < 500) {
    $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('UPDATE cards SET name=?, phone=?, phone2=?, email=?, zipcode=?, address=?, job=?, description=?, visibility=?, confirmed=?  WHERE id = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssisssiii', $name, $phone, $phone2, $email, $zipcode, $address, $job, $description, $visibility, $confirmed, $id);
    $success = $stmt -> execute();
    if ($success) {
        echo "Succes";
    }
} else {
    echo $mysqli -> error;
}
```

This way you can control the flow of your code much more easily and see which part actually goes wrong.
Also, in general, `if` statements with a lot of conditions lumped together are never a good idea because you can never be 100% sure of with condition is causing the `if` to not pass so they become a pain to test (as your case is proving).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should organize your code to keep actual conditions in `if` and put the code executing the query in the `if` code block. Also - are you sure this values for `strlen` are correct e.g. I know zipcode values much longer than 3 characters.
Also - do you actually want to check ALL of these parameters? I mean: maybe your query should be smarter to update only fields changed by the user.

Comment: In my Country, zipcodes are exactily 4 characters. And you were right, I was trying it with 4 characters, but I wrote < 4. That's why it didn't work. Thanks.